# ReactJS API to get all children of a rendered component

Tags: reactjs

I am looking for a way to get all children out of a React Component.

Example:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  render() {
    <div>
      <h1>Welcome!</h1>
      <ChildComponent />
    </div>
  }
}

const renderedComponent = <MyComponent />

React.Children(renderedComponent.props.children).forEach(() => {
  // Some logic
});
```

Problem: renderedComponent.props.children is empty. Is there any way to get the children in a way like this ?

My goal is to get all children recursively.

Comment: Why not do it inside the component?

Comment: In my case I have to do it outside - its for the Server Side Rendering process where I have to look for special children (in my case for example the Relay QueryRenderer). I just need it on SSR so thats why I dont want to do it inside the components.

Comment: Well technically your component doesn't have any children as far as React is concerned.
if you had something like:
`
    <MyComponent>
     <div>
       <span>Hello</span>
     </div>
    </MyComponent>
`
Then you would have one child (the root div).

Comment: So in the way I want to access all children (recursively) is not possible ? Then I would have to find another way :) Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [ReatDOMServer](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-dom-server.html#rendertostring) It seems like you will want to render your component to a string via `renderToString` and then parse the results with something like [jQuery.parseHTML](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)